# Difference between a Main class and a Controller class?

Tags: class, javafx

When I create a new JavaFX application in the ItelliJ IDE, it presents me with a templated Main class and an empty Controller class. Is there a difference between these classes? Isn't it possible to control the flow of events in the Main class and therefore making the Controller class useless? If not, could you please provide an example of the relationship between the Main and Controller classes?

Comment: I would use Main mostly as just an entry point to my application. It should handle any command line options, register any services, or other miscellanea needed to start up your application with a particular configuration. It can pass the configuration off to the controller, and start up any event loop if there is one. That's mostly a subjective preference though.

Comment: I believe you can, but I don't see much advantage on doing that. If this two classes were automatically created it may mean it`s some `best practice` stuff.

Comment: It is best to keep the code as simple as possible and by mixing `Main` with the `Controller`, there is nothing gained except complexity of the code.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` is just a starting point to et your application to run. In the `main()` of main, just call `Application.launch()` and pass it the fully qualified name of the class you want to launch as a `String`.

Yes, it is possible to add a `main()` to the `Controller` class but why muddle it all up ?